# For android using google signin it says access blocked Authorization error storagerely uri is not allowed for NATIVE_ANDROID

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-signin, mobile-application

I have flutter "android" app, I am implementing Google sign in and get this error:

> Access blocked: authorisation error Storagerelay URI is not allowed
> for 'NATIVE_ANDROID' client type. If you are a developer of
> project-111111111, see error details. Error 400: invalid_request

if you will suggest to use web client is, then tell me from where I get those two  uri required in making that as I have android app.

I have android App. Also tell if i can use this signin method or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it is:

In case of android app, still you have to make an Oauth2.0 for web application.
As for as the uri are concerned use:
http://localhost.com
http://localhost8888.com
Two uri for each field total of four.

Also make sure to http not https as you can get error this way.